# CKEDITOR 5 how disable caption

Tags: ckeditor5

I want to disable the captions under all images.

I tried, in file ckeditor_build.js :

```
        styles: [
            'alignLeft', 'alignCenter', 'alignRight',
            'toggleImageCaption', { focusCaptionOnShow: false }     
        ],
```

```
.then( newEditor  => {
    editor = newEditor ; 
    editor.execute( 'toggleImageCaption', { focusCaptionOnShow: false } );
} );
    editor.execute( 'toggleImageCaption' );
    editor.execCommand( 'toggleImageCaption' );
```

without success.

I also tried to hide the caption in the CSS, it works in part but there is still a huge frame, it is a failure.

thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by downloading the "ckeditor.js" file again.
`https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/30.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js`

By default the legends are not displayed so there is no parameter to configure.